# How to get the key element based on matching the key element in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
dictionary={
"ABC-6m-RF-200605-1352": "s3://blabla1.com",
"ABC-3m-RF-200605-1352": "s3://blabla2.com",
"DEF-6m-RF-200605-1352": "s3://blabla3.com"
 }
```

Now, I want to do a matching which takes input such as helper="ABC-6m" and tries to match this string to the key of the dictionary and returns the key (not the value)!

My code currently looks like this but it is not robust, i.e. sometimes it works and sometimes it does not:

```
dictionary_scan = dict((el, el[:7]) for el in dictionary)
#swapping key and value
dictionary_scan = dict((v, k) for k, v in dictionary.items())
#concat string components in helper variable
helper = 'ABC'+'-'+'6m'

out=list(value for key, value in dictionary_scan.items() if helper in key)
```

The expected output is: `'ABC-6m-RF-200605-1352'`. Sometimes this works in my code but sometimes it does not. Is there a better and more robust way to do this?

Comment: Do you ever have more than one key with the same prefix? You'll only find one of them this way.

Comment: ```helper = "ABC-6m";
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if helper in key:
        print(key)``` Wonder if there is something else you are looking for ?

Comment: Shouldn't swapping key and value use `dictionary_scan.items()`?

Comment: You don't need a second loop to swap key and value. Just change the first one to use `el[:7], el`

Answer (score 1):

If you make a dictionary that maps prefixes to full keys, you'll only be able to get one key with a given prefix.

If there can be multiple keys that start with `helper`, you need to check them all with an ordinary list comprehension.

```
out = [key for key in dictionary if key.startswith(helper)]
```